# Receiving multiple rows from a stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure with the following code, it works fine in sql server. I need to use the returned rows to work with the stacked column chart. I don't know how to receive these rows, though I have tried to do so with code given after the stored procedure code. I would really appreciate if anyone could find out where I am doing something wrong. Thank you :)

Stored Procedure Code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[weekly]

@id_beleg int           /* CONTAINS THE ID OF THE MACHINE FOR WHICH THE NUMBER OF ORDERS IS REQUIRED*/

AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @montag DATETIME            
DECLARE @weekend DATETIME

SET @montag = DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0)          
/* SET @MONTAG VARIABLE TO THE DATE ON MONDAY OF THE CURRENT WEEK*/

SET @weekend = dateadd(day, 6, @montag)                         
/* SET @WEEKEND VARIABLE TO THE DATE ON SUNDAY OF THE CURRENT WEEK*/

/* CONTAINS ALL RECORDS OF one PROCESS FOR THE CURRENT WEEK*/

CREATE TABLE #WeeklySieben
(
Tag datetime,

Aufträge_anzahl int,

Anlage varchar(30)
);

INSERT INTO #WeeklySieben (Tag, Aufträge_anzahl, Anlage)
SELECT * 
FROM 
    dbo.Sieben 

WHERE 
    Tag BETWEEN @montag AND GETDATE()

ORDER BY Tag


DECLARE @tempdate datetime

/* CONTAINS ONLY THE UNIQUE MACHINE NAMES*/

CREATE TABLE #Anlage_Sieben             
(   
Anl varchar(30)
)


/* CONTAINS DATE FOR ALL DAYS OF THE CURRENT WEEK*/


CREATE TABLE #alldays       
(   
days datetime
)



INSERT INTO #Anlage_Sieben (Anl)

SELECT      KURZTEXT    as Anl

FROM        dbo.tblBELEGUNGSEINHEIT

WHERE       ID  in (SELECT ID_BELEGUNGSEINHEIT FROM    dbo.tblPROZESS_BELEGUNGSEINHEIT WHERE ID_PROZESS = 5)    
/* SELECT MACHINE ID WHERE PROCESS IS number 5*/     



WHILE @montag <= @weekend

    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #alldays (days)
        SELECT days = @montag
        SET @tempdate= @montag
        SET @montag = dateadd(day, 1,@tempdate) 
    END


/* MACHINE NAME * WEEKDAYS DATE*/

CREATE TABLE #weekdays      
(

    daydate datetime,

Anlage varchar(30)
)


INSERT INTO #weekdays (daydate, Anlage)
SELECT      d.days as daydate
        , a.Anl as Anlage
FROM        #Anlage_Sieben a
CROSS JOIN  #alldays d



/* SELECT NUMBER OF ORDERS ON A PARTICULAR MACHINE FOR ALL WEEK DAYS*/

Select      case
        when Aufträge_anzahl is null then '0' 
        else Aufträge_anzahl    
        end  
from        #WeeklySieben W right join #weekdays wd on W.Anlage = wd.Anlage and W.Tag = wd.daydate 
where       wd.Anlage in (select KURZTEXT from dbo.tblBELEGUNGSEINHEIT where ID = @id_beleg  )

END
```

C# Code:

```
try
{
    int a;
    string sql = "weekly";
    SqlDataAdapter dp = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlCommand c = null;
    SqlDataReader r = null;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    //For creating 'raum' number of stacked column bars
    for (int i = 0; i < raum; i++)
    {
        c = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);                    
        c.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        c.Parameters.Add("@raumn", SqlDbType.Int).Value= (int)dblOrders[i];
        r = c.ExecuteReader();
        dp.SelectCommand = c;
        dp.Fill(ds, "Aufträge_anzahl");
        dt = ds.Tables["Aufträge_anzahl"];
        //For adding points to a stacked column bar
        for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            a = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[j]);
            Chart1.Series[seriesArray[j]].Points.AddY(a);
        } 

        Chart1.DataBind();
        dtSr.Clear();
    }
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("SQL Error" + ex.Message.ToString());
}
```

dblorders is the double array which holds the IDs for different machines, raum is the number of total machines. The code generates no error, but it does not retrieve back the data in the chart.

Comment: The SP requires one parameter named `@id_beleg` and you try to call it passing two parameters named `@raum` and `@outp`. I don't think that is wotking

Comment: Your SP is returning multiple tables. Check in code you are referring desired one.

Comment: But previously I tried without @outp, still it doesn't work